# Lost Launchpad configuration

Tags: dock, launchpad

If I move an app in Launchpad and then I "killall Dock" from the terminal, the Launchpad sometimes gets its previous configuration so my changes are lost. How can I restart the Dock without losing the Launchpad configuration?

Comment: Why do you restart Dock after changing the Launchpad configuration?

Comment: I'm a developer and I'm wondering what to do if an user restarts the Dock (losing the Launchpad configuration)

Comment: Though it’s pretty unlikely that a normal user would restart Dock randomly, you should know that Launchpad configuration isn’t written to disk as soon as changes are made. They are written to disk at certain intervals.

Comment: Can I force those changes to be written to disk?

Comment: To answer that I would like to know something. How exactly are you modifying the Launchpad?

Comment: Manually, normal things a "standard" user would do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4623/discussion-between-deepanshu-utkarsh-and-egon1984)

Comment: Lion or Mountain Lion for OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Something like `osascript -e 'quit app "Dock"'` might work. If not, you could also quit and reopen Dock by logging out and back in.

Comment: Yes, it should work since the Dock is not killed but properly stopped. I'll try that, thank you